# looking for youtube api tutorials or assistance to make a Phone 7 Youtube Compainion Application

Tags: windows-phone-7, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

I am new to phone 7 development and I am looking to make an app that will do this. I want to make a small simple app that has my channel as primary subscription to monitor for new videos, comments etc. (also have a live panel that has a count of new videos uploaded) and then open up in the default player to watch it.

I also want to have the availability to also add others into a second list that shows up to notify changes that you can then look into the second screen which shows the selected other channel.

are they any tutorials on the YouTube API's on how to authenticate with the users YouTube account, retrieve their subscriptions list and the video list

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to developing for the phone I'd suggest you start with something simpler and work your way up to the app you describe. You should become familiar with the nuances of the platform before having to deal with the special challenges which integrating with YouTube presents.

In the mean time, you can read about the YouTube APIs at http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html